# Why" The origin for the sensor at is out of map bounds" warning after configuring roboot_localization

Tags: imu, navigation, pose, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I added an IMU to improve odometery and used robot_localozation to fuze odom and IMU data. I speficied the initial pose in ekf configs but my robot wont get its initial pose on the map properly. If I rum move_base not without robot_localization locates to its initial pose just fine on the map. How can I get it to position to its initial pose on the map when its using robot_localization??

Below you will my ekf config file, my cosmap files local and global and launch file for move base.

EKF config:

```
frequency: 30

silent_tf_failure: false

two_d_mode: true

transform_time_offset: 0.5

transform_timeout: 0.5

print_diagnostics: true

debug: false

publish_tf: true

publish_acceleration: false

map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified but if map specified USE MAP (Check AMCL)


odom0: /odom

odom0_config: [false, false,  false,
               false, false, false,
               true,  true,  false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]


imu0: example/imu
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false,  true,
              true,  true,  false]

use_control: false

stamped_control: false


process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]


initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

Local costmap:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom 
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3.0 #**was5 -4
  publish_frequency: 2.0 #was2-4
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
```

Global costmap:

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 3.0 # was3
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: false
  transform_tolerance: 0.5
  allow_unknown: false
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395784/why%22-the-origin-for-the-sensor-at-is-out-of-map-bounds%22-warning--after-configuring--roboot_localization/) by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2022-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-02-25**:
You need a lot more information here:

- What is generating the odom->base_link transform? Your EKF is just doing map->odom.
- Are you using amcl or something? You can't have two nodes publishing the robot's map frame pose.

I think you should read [REP-105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), but then you need to give more detail about what nodes you are running.

**Comment by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) on 2022-03-03**:
@ Tom, Thank you for your response. I am actually using EKF for fusing sensors and AMCL for localization. Thanks to your response, I just realized that I have EKF publishing TF also. I will set this option to false and report back the results. Thanks again.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2022-03-17**:
OK, please don't forget to update this question with an answer when you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good Afternoon Tom,

Your suggestion to check which node were publishing was on point. I stopped EKF from publishing and all is working fine now. Thanks again.

---

Originally posted by [chm007](https://answers.ros.org/users/55617/chm007/) with karma: 34 on 2022-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0